# Cannot Get FontAwesome Working in IE 11 with MVC 5

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, font-awesome

I have a new MVC 5 Project and I am trying to get FontAwesome to display icons from the _Layout page.  It works fine in Chrome, Firefox, and even the Page Inspector in Visual Studio.  When I launch the site in IE 11, it just shows a blank space.

What I've tried so far:

- Making sure the font-awesome.css and fonts are being downloaded to the browser
- Checking the paths to the directory where the fonts exists is correct
- Loading from the BundleConfig and just putting the links directly on the Layout page
- Installing FontAwesome using Nuget and tried an Nuget Html Helper for FontAwesome
- Tried added MIME types for the fonts to the web.config
- Tried using CDNs and Fully qualified paths instead of relative links
- Tried several variations of the markup
- Validated no errors in the Console or 404s in the Network Debugger

I'm not sure what else I can try and feel like I've spent WAAAY to much time just trying to get some icons to work.  It's just frustrating because the site looks really good in Chrome and Firefox.

I am using a Template I downloaded from WrapBootstrap, but their examples work in IE 11, and I've tried to mimick their markup as best I can.

Below is the markup in the Layout page I am using and this comes directly from their Template and it works in FF/Chrome.

```
<i class="icon-dashboard"></i>
```

and I tried

```
<i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>
```

Any guidance on troubleshooting would be appreciated.

Comment: does it work if you get fontawesome from the CDN <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: No, I tried that and got the same results.  Works in Chrome/FF, but not in IE.

Comment: It's not really that complicated. If it works in Chrome and Firefox it will work in IE11. My guess is that you've either switched the rendering engine to IE7 at some point and forgot, accidentally clicked the compatibility mode button (which renders as IE7), or otherwise are working in compatibility mode (depending on your local or GP settings, if this is a work machine, compatibility mode may be the default for local and/or intranet sites).

Comment: @ChrisPratt Thank you so much!!  During some earlier troubleshooting, I had put this site in compatibility mode, but didn't take it off.  You were dead on.  I wish it were as easy for me as it is for you.  Make this an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Done. Glad you were able to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really that complicated. If it works in Chrome and Firefox it will work in IE11. My guess is that you've either switched the rendering engine to IE7 at some point and forgot, accidentally clicked the compatibility mode button (which renders as IE7), or otherwise are working in compatibility mode (depending on your local or GP settings, if this is a work machine, compatibility mode may be the default for local and/or intranet sites).

Comment: thank you! I tore my hair out for a day on this (it was for Glyphicons, not FontAwesome). Most hits on SO and elsewhere are about MIME types, font lib locations, etc., and those were all good. It worked on IE against localhost but not the machine name. Worked in Chrome and Firefox. Turned out to be the fact that I am developing an intranet app and our IE policy at work has Compatibility View turned on by default for intranet sites. The fix (since we depend on that behavior for many other apps) was to use the `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10"/>` approach.

Comment: For what it's worth, your infrastructure team can simply manage a list of sites, intranet or not, that need Compatibility Mode, instead of forcing everything carte blanc on the intranet to use it. It's just a little bit more difficult than clicking a single checkbox and going to lunch.

Comment: Yes, but in our case that list would be, "Most of the intranet." At this point it is easier to add the meta tag on a project-by-project basis to the master/layout pages as we build new apps. Hopefully in the future the vendors of our LOB apps will catch up with the 21st century and then we can start making Compatibility View the exception and not the norm. I just wish there was a way to raise this SO question and answer higher in the search rankings!

Answer (score 2):

I just had this issue but found that it was actually caused by the fact the font files reside on a different subdomain. Adding an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header when serving the fonts solves the problem.

**Apache .htaccess snippet**

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

**nginx virtual host file snippet**

```
location ~* \.(eot|otf|ttf|woff)$ {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
}
```

More information can be found [here](http://red-team-design.com/firefox-doesnt-allow-cross-domain-fonts-by-default/) (original source for snippets).

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility (which I just spend 4 hours debugging) is that IE-11 is falling back to an older document compatibility mode without your knowledge. The thing to do is make sure the auto-detected target really reads "Edge". In my case it was blank.

- The files were downloading.
- The MIME types and headers were right.
- My document had the right compatibility meta tag set.
- I could surf just fine.
- The console showed no JS errors (or errors of any kind).

Yet still no Fontawesome.

Turns out if your HD is running low on space as my VM was and the available temp cache falls below a certain size, IE silently reverts to showing all websites in compatibility mode (no matter what your settings are in regard to when to use compatibility mode).

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your web.config. It should work for Font-awesome 4.7:

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
      <remove fileExtension=".eot" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
      <remove fileExtension=".otf" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml"  />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".eot" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-fontobject" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="font/woff2" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".otf" mimeType="application/font-sfnt" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```